# Using serial number with paginate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to retrieve serial number in the blade template with variable `i`:

```
    <?php $i=0;?>
    @foreach ($lists as $li)
    <tr><td><?php $i++;?>{{$i}}</td><td>{{$li->Name}}</td><td>{{$li->Telephone}}
    </td><td>{{$li->mobile}}</td>
    @endforeach
    {!! $lists->render() !!}
```

but I am using paginate in the controller:

```
$lists=telephone::orderBy('name')->simplePaginate(10);
```

So, the first page's serial number is ok. But for the second page `i` starts from 1 again.

Comment: yo need to multiply the page size with `$i`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The solution below starts from 0 instead of 1 for the first page. To start from 1:

```
$i = ($lists->perPage() * ($lists->currentPage() - 1)) + 1;
```

---

Try setting `$i` to `$lists->perPage() * ($lists->currentPage() - 1)`

```
$i = $lists->perPage() * ($lists->currentPage() - 1);
```

Comment: This is something i mean.

Comment: but the problem is, number is starting from 0 not 1. how to solve it?

Comment: @MilanBastola A way to do this is to add 1 to the result of the above operation: `$i = ($lists->perPage() * ($lists->currentPage() - 1)) + 1;`

Comment: This one works perfectly for me: `$i = $lists->perPage() * ($lists->currentPage() - 1) + 1;`

Comment: The question about s.no, means start from 1 to so on .
your solution just repeat the same count from 1 to 10 in every page , it's not a proper  solution

Comment: @SirajAli Feel free to post the "correct" solution. :)

Comment: @Doom5 yes it was my pagination issue, your answer is correct. thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can also use

```
@foreach($lists as $index => $list)
   {{$index + $lists->firstItem()}} //S.N
@endforeach
```

`$index` is the row number in that result set and [$lists->firstItem()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#paginator-instance-methods) will get the result number of the first item in the paginated results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel paginate/simplePaginate you can get the first item number with the laravel provided function like the below code.

```
<?php $i = $lists->firstItem(); ?>
```